# [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$slug" of required type "String!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am trying to use slug as url but its not working. I get error in console something like this.

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$slug" of required type "String!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

This is my code.
Although it is working fine if i use id instead of slug. I am getting these data from wordpress wp-graphql api.

> graphql/queries/post.js

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';    
export const SinglePostDetail = gql`
  query SinglePostDetail($slug: String!) {
    postBy(slug: $slug) {
      id
      slug
      title
      date
      content
      categories{
        nodes {
          name
        }
      }
      author {
        name
      }
      featuredImage {
        sourceUrl
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

> views/postDetail.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import { SinglePostDetail } from '../graphql/queries/posts'
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import Loader from '../components/Loader/loading';
import './postDetail.scss';

class PostDetail extends Component {   
    constructor () {
        super()
        this.renderPost = this.renderPost.bind(this)
    }
     render() {
         const isLoading = this.props.data.loading
         return (
             <Layout>
                 {isLoading && <Loader/>}
                 {!isLoading && this.renderPost()}
             </Layout>
         )
     }
     renderPost () {
    const post = this.props.data.postBy
    console.log(post);
    const date = new Date(post.date).toLocaleDateString()
    return (
      <div className=" container has-text-centered postdetail__wrapper">
        <h2 className="subtitle">{post.author.name}</h2>
        <h1 className="title is-2">{post.title}</h1>

        <h5 className="subtitle is-7">{post.categories.nodes.name}</h5>
        <h5 className="subtitle is-7">{date}</h5>
        <img
            alt={post.title}
            src={post.featuredImage && post.featuredImage.sourceUrl}
        />
        <div className="postdetail__content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />
      </div>
    )
  }
  }



export default graphql(SinglePostDetail, {
    options: ({match}) => ({variables: {slug: match.params.slug}})
})(PostDetail);
```

> Routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter,Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './views/Home';
import About from './views/About';
import Contact from './views/Contact';
import Category from './views/Category';
import PostDetail from './views/PostDetail';
import Blog from './views/Blog';

function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
          <Route path="/blog" component={Blog}/>          
          <Route path='/category/:slug' component={Category}/>
          <Route path="/post/:slug" component={PostDetail}/>
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

if I log props.data i get something like this.

> console.log(props.data);

```
error: Error: GraphQL error: No resource could be found at new ApolloError fetchMore: ƒ ()
loading: false
networkStatus: 7
refetch: ƒ ()
startPolling: ƒ ()
stopPolling: ƒ ()
subscribeToMore: ƒ ()
updateQuery: ƒ ()
variables:
slug: "cG9zdDo1NA=="
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: The error indicates that the value for the `slug` variable is undefined, so you're likely not passing in the variable correctly. Please include the relevant code that shows how you're actually using this query inside your app.

Comment: If you log `match.params.slug` to the console, is it defined?

Comment: it says undefined

Comment: but it is working fine in graphiql

Comment: This is not a GraphQL issue. The point is that you're asking for a param that apparently doesn't exist. What's the path for the `Route` component that's being matched by your router? Assuming you're using react-router, the path of the matched route would need to include `:slug` in order for `match.params.slug` to be defined. For example, if your path is `/foo/:id`, then `match.params.id` will be defined. If your path is `/foo/:bar` then `match.params.bar` will be defined.

Comment: @DanielRearden I did that but its still not working. I have updated my question have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a `Relay` Global ID as a `slug`. That why it works when you use the `id` parameter instead.

`slug: "cG9zdDo1NA=="` <- This is what you're passing as a `$slug`. You probably have an error in how you're navigating to the page. Check out your `NavLink` or `Link` component if you're using one.

Either change to the actually post `slug` or modify your query like so

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';    
export const SinglePostDetail = gql`
  query SinglePostDetail($id: ID!) {
    post(id: $id) {
      id
      slug
      title
      date
      content
      categories{
        nodes {
          name
        }
      }
      author {
        name
      }
      featuredImage {
        sourceUrl
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

`[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$slug" of required type "String!" was not provided.` <- This error is because the what being passed is of the type ID.